# worst case for a binary search if you're not dealing with a power of 2

Tags: binary

I understand that in the worst case the number of guesses needed for a binary search is lg(n)+1 where n is the number of elements you're searching.  I understand this completely, but this obviously only gives you a nice number if n is a power of 2.  If n is not a power of 2 I'm told you simply go up to the next power of 2.  So for example 5 would go up to 8 then lg(8) +1= 4.  But if you were dealing with 5 elements worst case would be 3 guesses?  What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The actual formula is *floor( log(n) + 1)* (using base-2 *log*).  Thus, *floor( log(5) + 1 )* = *floor( 2.x + 1 )* = *floor( 3.x )* = 3.

Comment: This was incredibly helpful, thank you.  I was reading things that explicitly stated the formula without the floor function and I couldn't figure out what I was missing.